# Do the jBPM 5.4 WARs run under Wildfly 8.0?

Tags: jboss, jbpm, wildfly

I have just gotten Wildfly 8.0 running and integrated with Eclipse (Kepler).  I've tried to deploy the following jBPM 5.4 files:

```
designer
drools-guvnor
jbpm-form-builder
jbpm-gwt-console
jbpm-gwt-console-server
jbpm-human-task-war
```

but they do not deploy - numerous errors.  I just placed them in the .\deployments folder which works under JBoss 7.1.   Is this expected behavior?  Does this mean that if I want to run Wildfly (which fixes the failure to clean up the 1GB of deployed jBPM files upon shutdown) I have to upgrade everything to the jBPM 6 CR2?

Thank you.
Al

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to upgrade to 6.x, we are all working with that version now, so if you have troubles with that let us know and we can looking to fix it.

Comment: I've had a very hard time integrating jBPM 5.4 support into an existing servlet (under JBoss 7.1).  I can execute the 1st line of the evaluation sample (in the jBPM 5.4 Full Install) after copying that to the servlet but I am now stuck on executing the 2nd line in evaluation (after adding that line to my servlet):
kbuilder.add(ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource("Evaluation.bpmn"), ResourceType.BPMN2);
I don't understand why copying all of the .\runtime files (from Full Install) to my WEB-INF\lib doesn't work.  I'll try moving to Wildfly with jBPM 6 if you think that will be easier.  Thanks.

Comment: I have tried to shift gears and see if I have better luck figuring out how to get jBPM 6.0.0CR2 running.  I installed the Full Install with no errors and Juno comes up fine.  But I have two questions:
1) Under 5.4 (and JBoss 7.1) we had six jBPM WAR files being deployed.  Now I am seeing only one (jbpm-console) as deployed (in the JBoss Admin console).  Have the other five files been eliminated - is this single WAR correct?
2) I have Imported the evaluation sample into Juno but I can't run it as I could in 5.4; there is no Run/Debug As Application available.  Please help.
Thank you.

Comment: It's worth noting that even with JBPM 6, Wildfly 8 probably will not work. The installer script `ant install.demo` downloads JBoss Application Server 7.1.1.Final. So I suspect Wildfly won't work yet.